# Intellij inspections unwanted warnings with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, angularjs-components, code-inspection

I'm using intellij for angular project, and it works good except of some inspections: 
[image]

intellij marks angular components and $ctrl as warnings...

How can I configure intellij to ignore this warnings?